# iCloud - NSMetadataQuery not sorting with NSMetadataItemFSCreationDateKey

Tags: ios, iphone, sorting, icloud, nsmetadataquery

I am getting list of files in array from iCloud, I want that files in sorting order either with `NSMetadataItemFSCreationDateKey` or `NSMetadataItemFSContentChangeDateKey`. But it's not returning as per given `NSSortDescriptor`.

Here is my code, please suggest me if anything is missing or i need to add anything.

```
-(void)getiCloudData
{

[appdel.metadataQuery setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope,NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope ,nil]];
[appdel.metadataQuery setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE '*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey]];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:NSMetadataItemFSCreationDateKey
                             ascending:FALSE] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            sortDescriptor,
                            nil];
[appdel.metadataQuery setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(queryDidReceiveNotification:)
                                         name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
                                       object:appdel.metadataQuery];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(updatequeryDidReceiveNotification:)
                                         name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification
                                       object:appdel.metadataQuery];
   [appdel.metadataQuery enableUpdates];
   [appdel.metadataQuery startQuery];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `NSMetadataItemFSCreationDateKey` always returns as nil, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632515/nsmetadataitemfscreationdatekey-is-always-null-for-my-icloud-nsmetadataitems), so don't even try sorting on that.

Now, I don't sort by `NSMetadataItemFSContentChangeDateKey`, though I do query it using valueForAttribute: from the NSMetadataItem when the query results come through and that works fine at that point.  So focus your efforts on `NSMetadataItemFSContentChangeDateKey`.

If you can't get the query results to come through sorted, one possible approach is to sort the results *after* you get them through - when you're processing your query results.  I've used that when I've had an unusual sorting requirement in the past.

Comment: Well, In my case it's returning value with key "NSMetadataItemFSCreationDateKey" but not in sorted order. And yes I had did the same way as after get result.

Comment: yup by using NSMetadataItemFSCreationDateKey, on iOS6 it's returning nil array, on iOS7 it's working fine.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the update - hadn't realised they'd fixed that one on iOS 7.